# Use pages that need authentication (locked pages) in storybook stories

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a React page that is locked when the user is logged out. I've created a simple story for that page but it doesn't show up in the dashboard (served using `yarn storybook`)

.storybook/main.js

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"], 
  addons: [                                                                     
    {         
      name: "@storybook/addon-docs",
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,                                        
      },
    },          
    "@storybook/addon-links",       
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",                   
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",                                                                               
  ],                                                                                                                    
};
```

LockedPage.stories.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Story, Meta } from "@storybook/react/types-6-0";

import {
  Props,
  AirplaneOnBoarding as AirplaneOnBoardingComponent,
} from "../pages/aircarft-onboarding/aircarft-onboarding";         

export default {
  title: "Pages/AirplaneOnboarding",
  component: AirplaneOnBoardingComponent,            
} as Meta;                                                                  
                                                                            
const Template: Story<Props> = (args) => (                                  
  <AirplaneOnBoardingComponent {...args} />                                 
);                                                                          
                                                                            
export const AirplaneOnboarding = Template.bind({});
AirplaneOnboarding.args = {};
```

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Qe1.png)

Can someone please help me debug this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on the needs of the AirplaneOnboarding page. If the component is not shown in the sidebar of your Storybook, it's likely that:

1. Your glob defined in your main.js `"../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"` is not matching `LockedPage.stories.tsx`.
2. There is something broken in your stories file + component. If that's the case, you'd see a few logs with the error when you open the dev tools.

All in all, if you want to add a page that requires certain checks such as authentication, you need to do one of these options:

- Make Storybook smart enough to understand those checks. This means you need to add [decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) that provide such functionality. You could create a decorator that wraps the component and sets up the correct steps to set authentication. If you're setting a flag in the state with Redux for instance, you could create a decorator that injects the state with that flag set to true already.
- Restructure your page component to use a container pattern, where the authentication checks and redirection would be done in the container, and the presentational component would be pure. In this scenario, it's really simple to use it in Storybook.
- Mock your dependencies. You could use something like [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to mock the http requests, making them return what you want.. or you could use [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) to fully mock whatever import you want, similar to how jest mock dependencies.

Just remember that Storybook behaves similarly to React. By default, your `App.jsx` is quite "dumb". You need to add decorators (providers) to make it smart enough for your use cases. In Storybook it's the same.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the thorough explanation!